# Views is not connected with File's Owner in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new in objective-c.I am making controls like calculator.After double click on calc.xib file i am getting 3 pops i designed some control and wanting to connect with "File's Owner" with the ControlKey(a strength blue line) in Mac but unfortunate this is not being connect to "File's Owner".What is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your nib file is MainMenu.nib, then it is not to the File's Owner, which is an object of type `NSApplication` in that case, that you should connect your controls.

Either you define a controller (any object derived from `NSObject`) or you can use the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: It is connecting with view automatically and output is looking same.TY for ur reply.

Comment: File’s Owner must be of type `NSApplication` in MainMenu.nib only. Other nib files can have owners of other classes, which is particularly true for nib files supposed to be loaded by window or view controllers.

Comment: You are right. the fact is that in the context of the question, my guess was that he was trying to connect to his NSApplication, and in fact I was right. But I lost in completeness. anyway, thanks for your comment, I have updated the answer so that no reader can be mislead.